# Using 7-zip command line from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, command-line, 7zip

As a result of running a macro I've one folder containing various file types: .err, .txt, .sh, .fat ..

If for instance I want that macro to compress only the .fat files this works pretty well:

```
ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7z.exe a " & " " & Chr(34) & NameZipFile & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & FolderName & Chr(34) & "*.fat"
```

where (I'm trying to keep this as neat as possible):

1. PathZipProgram -> 7zip directory
2. NameZipFile ->   Output.zip file
3. FolderName-> Input.zip file

Instead, if I want to zip only some of those files (e.g. only *.fat and *.sh) reading the 7-zip command line manual it seems that :

```
ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7z.exe a " & " " & Chr(34) & NameZipFile & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & FolderName & Chr(34) & "*.fat -i*.sh"
```

should also work but it doesn't. Could anyone with more experience help me sorting this out?

Comment: Please just mark LS_Dev's answer as the accepted answer. That's enough to show that the question has been "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may find in 7-Zip command line syntax:

```
7z <command> [<switch>...] <base_archive_name> [<arguments>...]

<arguments> ::= <switch> | <wildcard> | <filename> | <list_file>
```

So you just have to repeat your source content:

```
ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7z.exe a """ & NameZipFile & """ """ & FolderName & "\*.fat"" """ & FolderName & "\*.sh"""
```

Tip: You can escape quotes in strings doubling then.